# String from Vector is saved with spaces in file

Tags: c++, powershell, file, email, smtp

At the moment I am programming a program that sends an email to the whole Outlook contact list. The program fetches the emails from a vector. When I output the string normally, it is output correctly, but when I write it into the text (or ps1) file, there is a space between each character, which makes the following code (i.e. the sending) impossible.

```
for (std::string mail : resolved_mails) {
if (std::filesystem::exists("test.ps1")) {
  remove("test.ps1");

}
std::ofstream ps;

ps.open("test.ps1", std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::app);

const char* fileLPCWSTR = "test.ps1";
int attr = GetFileAttributes((LPCSTR)fileLPCWSTR);

if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0) {
  SetFileAttributes(fileLPCWSTR, attr | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
}


std::string powershell;
powershell += "\n";
std::cout << mail << std::endl;
powershell += "$EmailTo = '" + mail + "'\n";
powershell += "$EmailFrom = '" + EmailFrom + "'\n";
powershell += "$Subject = '" + Subject + "'\n";
powershell += "$Body = '" + Body + "'\n";
powershell += "$SMTPServer = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'\n";
powershell += "$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)\n";
powershell += "$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)\n";
powershell += "$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true\n";
powershell += "$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('" + Email + "', '" + Passw + "');\n";
powershell += "$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)\n";

std::cout << powershell << std::endl;

ps << powershell;

ps.close();
Sleep(2000);
system("powershell.exe test.ps1");
std::cout << "sended mail to" << mail << std::endl;
Sleep(1000);
```

[This is how it looks in the .ps1 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bCOP.png)

When I print out the powershell string, it gets printed out normally without spaces.

Comment: Can you point your finger to exact line in the shown code you believe writes anything, to any `.ps1` file? And explain why it is necessary to check for the file's existance, and if so remove it, for every iteration in the `resolved_mail` vector? Do you anticipate that something might create that file while that code is busy iterating over the vector?

Comment: I first collect all the lines in one string and then i write the string in the ps file with ps<<powershell; 
i noticed that it does not work when the file exists always and doesnt get deleted

Comment: Check if the generated mail has null characters. For example `mail@example.com` can be `"m\0a\0i\0l\0@\0e\0x\0a\0m\0p\0l\0e\0.\0c\0o\0m"`.

Comment: I deleted the part where it removes the file. It didnt do anything.

Comment: What is the type of the `mail` variable? Where id it come from? Consider a [mcve] so we can see the full picture. It looks like `mail` is a wide string.

Comment: @Plantt Ive added a NullCharacterRemove but it still writes the spaces between each character:
'static std::string removeNulls(std::string str) {
    str.erase(std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), '\0'), str.end());
    return str;
}'

Comment: @RetiredNinja mail is a normal string (as u can see in the first line, it does a foreach for the vector).

Comment: @Vkastei `int attr = GetFileAttributes((LPCSTR)fileLPCWSTR);` -- Remove the `(LPCSTR)` cast and recompile your code.  Do you now get a compiler error?  If so, read the error carefully, as it is telling you that you're doing something wrong.  String types should never have to be casted just to make the compiler "shut up".  It indicates there is a flaw in your string handling.

Comment: @Vkastei *there is a space between each character,* -- If you had not done that ill-advised cast of `LPCSTR` I mentioned, probably you would have had been forced to actually fix the string types being used, or call the [appropriate function(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa) that handles the character types you are dealing with.  So I wouldn't be surprised if that simple cast you had done made you go down the wrong path, giving you a program that, unfortunately, compiled successfully.

Comment: @Vkastei Also, `for (std::string mail : resolved_mails)` -- More than likely, your issues started before that `for` loop is executed, where `resolved_mails` was populated with wide strings, but you (or some function) treated them as if they are non-wide.  That's probably why you see the space characters.  Given how you used those casts in the code you did post, I wouldn't be surprised if you are making the same mistakes elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So i deleted the piece of code now, but it still doesnt work. I g its because of the encoding, cause maybe the encoding of the email string is different from the file writing encoding.

Comment: @Vkastei -- Whether it works or not wasn't really the point.  The point I was making is that you *never* cast string types in the belief that the compiler will change the encoding depending on the cast -- the compiler is not that smart.  You remove all the casts of string types, and either replace them with the proper types, or call the functions that work with the types you have now *without casting*.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ive checked the rest of the code, and when i add the strings to the vector, there is no widestring, just a normal string.
`for (std::string line; getline(contacts, line);) {
       
        try
        {
            unsigned first = line.find("(");
            unsigned last = line.find_last_of(")");

            std::string strNew = line.substr(first + 1, last - first -1);
            
           
            if (strNew.find("@") != std::string::npos){
  resolved_mails.push_back(strNew);
                std::cout << strNew << std::endl;   
            } 
        }`

Comment: That code doesn't prove what is in the string itself.  A `std::string` could contain anything.  A proof would be to print out each character, or display each character, or even get the `size()`.  If you see spaces in that string when you actually inspect it, then you need to see why and who put the spaces in there.  The code you posted doesn't do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually the size of the string is 41 even tho there are only 20 characters. How could i change that? does  a std::string::resize do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

K, i got it.
This was the code i added to remove the whitespace from the str, so the size of the string was normal again:

```
std::string str;
        int index = 1;
        for (char c : strNew) {
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                str.push_back(c);
            }
            index++;
        }
```

Comment: All you had to do was `strNew.erase(std::remove(strNew.begin(), strNew.end(),'\0'), strNew.end());`.  Removing a value from a sequence doesn't require writing `for` loops.

Comment: I tried the exact same thing but it didnt work.